# symfony2 output data from OneToMany entity TWIG

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I get following exception, when trying to output all attachments ( Attachment Entity ) associated with a task. But I don't know why.

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: task in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Seotool/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1753") in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Seotool/src/Seotool/MainBundle/Resources/views/Task/load_task.html.twig at line 10.

TWIG:

```
{{ tasks.taskDescription }}
{% for attachment in tasks.Attachments %}
    {{ attachment.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Controller:

```
/**
@Route(
 *     path = "/tasks/load/{id}",
 *     name = "load_task"
 * )
 * @Template()
 */
public function load_taskAction($id, Request $request)
{

    $tasks = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('SeotoolMainBundle:Task')
        ->find($id);

    return array(
        'tasks' => $tasks
    );

}
```

Task Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Attachments", mappedBy="task",cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $attachments;
```

Attachments Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Task", inversedBy="attachments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="task", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $Task;
```

Comment: change protected $Task; to protected $task;
you may get another error in twig line:
{% for attachment in tasks.Attachments %} change it to
{% for attachment in tasks.attachments %}

Comment: you are welcome :). does that work correctly before changing $Task?***
in your addAttachment() method put this $attachment->addTask($this);

Comment: All is good now. In my Attachments.php was @setTask this: $this->Task = $task; but it has to be $this->task = $task; now all works great.

Answer (score 1):

```
mappedBy="task"
```

probably should be

```
mappedBy="Task"
```

or better Task property should begin with a lowercase letter, this is more standard aproach. In that case you should change this reference:

```
targetEntity="Task"
```